# Method System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName not found when creating an application installer WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, .net-5

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error MSB4186 Invalid static method invocation syntax:
> "[System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName(C:\Users\emmet\OneDrive - CBRE,
> Inc\Work\SourceTree\CBREDesktopApplication%28Net5Dev%29\CBRE
> Application\CBRE Application.csproj)". Method
> 'System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName' not found. Static method invocation
> should be of the form: $([FullTypeName]::Method()), e.g.
> $([System.IO.Path]::Combine(`a`, `b`)). Check that all parameters are
> defined, are of the correct type, and are specified in the right
> order.    Application Installer   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\DesktopBridge\Microsoft.DesktopBridge.targets 602

When attempting to create an `application installer` for a `WPF application`, I get this error code on Visual Studio 2019. Any ideas? Project is `.Net 5.0`

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/graph-oauth?view=odsp-graph-online

Comment: Does this also occur if the project is in a path without such special characters?

Comment: Klaus, I will try that in a few minutes.

Comment: Hi,@Charles Jennings. Has your problem been solved? Or is there any update?